# Does MSBuild resolve project to project references when building a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

MSDN docs [Visual Studio Integration (MSBuild)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx) state:

> ### Building Solutions
>
> Within Visual Studio, the solution file and project build ordering are
> controlled by Visual Studio itself. When *building a solution* with
> **msbuild.exe on the command line**, MSBuild parses the solution file and
> orders the project builds. In both cases **the projects are built
> individually in dependency order, and project to project references
> are not traversed**. In contrast, when *individual projects* are built
> with msbuild.exe, project to project references are traversed.

With my Visual Studio 2010, when building a `.sln` file with MSBuild from the command line, project to project references are *all* built, regardless whether they occur in the solution.

What did I miss here? Or are the docs plain wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that msbuild.exe will sort out all project references whether or not they are part of the solution in contrast to building within Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013/2015 (and possibly later versions) where you will get a build failure if a referenced project is not part of the solution or built beforehand.

In short, yes, the documentation seems a bit off.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the build of project to project reference by running    msbuild Solution.sln /t:ProjectName /p:BuildProjectReferences=false  this explain the sentence in msdn.

Comment: Adding /p:BuildProjectReferences=false will also cause MsBuild to not build project references that are part of the solution. This causes the build to fail, if a project contains a project reference to one of the other projects that exist in the solution.